# Solving a triple integral with modulus

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multiple-integral

I really can't figure out how to solve this triple integral
$$
\iiint_D|z|dxdydz
$$

on the domain $D$, that is so defined

$$
D = \left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2-16 \leq z \leq 4 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right\}
$$

Any ideas or solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to change from cartesian to polar coordinates - this makes it a lot easier to describe the region $D$, as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\rightarrow r$. Find for which values of $r$ the inequality that describes $D$ can be satisfied - that is, for which values of $r$ is $r^2-16<4-r$. Then seperate the $z$-integral into two integrals - one for positive values of $z$ and one for negative values to get rid of the absolute value. Once you have done that, the integration itself should be fairly easy.

Comment: You mean a spherical coordinate system or a cylindrical one?

Comment: Cylindrical coordinates is what I meant, sorry for being unclear. Spherical just makes things complicated in the $z$ direction, which isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this way then!

Comment: I got the result  $-\dfrac{344}{3}\pi$... Hope it is the right one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the coordinates to cylindrical ones with a diffeomorphism  $\Psi $, 
$$
\Psi^{-1}(D)=\{(\rho,\theta,z): \rho ^2-16\leq z\leq 4-\rho\} = $$
$$
\{(\rho,\theta,z)\in \mathbb R_+ \times(0,2\pi)\times \mathbb R|\rho \in [-5,4], \
 z \in [\rho ^2-16,4-\rho] \}. 
$$

$D$ is measurable and so is $\Psi^{-1}(D) $. So by changing coordinates and Fubini's theorem you have:
$$
\int_D |z| dx dy dz =\iiint_{\Psi^{-1}(D)} |z|\rho d\rho d\theta dz=$$
$$=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-5}^4 \int _{\rho ^2-16}^{4-\rho} |z|\rho dz d\rho d\theta=$$
$$=2\pi \int_{-5}^4 \rho\int _{\rho ^2-16}^{4-\rho} |z| dz d\rho.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Only, I don't understand why $\rho$ has to be $\in [4,5]$. Could you provide also an entire solution? I would be very grateful. Thx anyway!

Comment: @opisthofulax it's obvious I have mistaken. $\rho \in [-5,4]$ so when you integrate you must split the integral because of the absolute value of z. Sorry. I'm going to change the answer as soon as possible